# Python quicksort not sorting right side

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Here is my input:

```
[3, 9, 8, 4, 6, 10, 2, 5, 7, 1]
```

Here is my code (called count for another reason which isn't yet implemented):

```
def Count(num_list):
global comparisons


if len(num_list) > 1:
    pivot = num_list[0]
    print "Pivot value is: %s, current list is: %s" % (pivot, num_list)
    i = 1
    j = 1

    for j in range(len(num_list)):
        if num_list[j] < pivot:
            print "Swapping %s and %s" % (num_list[i], num_list[j])
            num_list[i], num_list[j] = num_list[j], num_list[i]
            print "List is now: %s" % (num_list)
            i += 1


    num_list[0], num_list[i-1] = num_list[i-1], num_list[0]
    print "List before next recursive step: %s" % num_list

    Count(num_list[:(len(num_list)/2)])
    Count(num_list[(len(num_list)/2):])

print "List at the end of function: %s" % (num_list)
```

I get the following result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 5, 7, 8]
```

As I look at all of the debug print statements I made, I see it's not putting together the right half the way it does the left half, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: http://codexpi.com/quicksort-python-iterative-recursive-implementations/ 30 seconds on google.

Comment: @Pythonista That isn't his question, as that would be off topic. His question is about his specific implementation.

Comment: Your code will only split the list into two with one half being higher than the pivot and one half being lower. It doesn't sort the list.

Comment: The indentation looks broken.

Comment: You may have a problem in `j = 1` `for j in range(len(num_list)):` What are the first few values for `j`?

Comment: @greybeard - even if for  j ... starts off with j == 0, it won't matter because num_list[0] is the pivot, so num_list[0[ wont' be < pivot. It's just a wasted loop.

Comment: The code is sorting sliced copies of the array. The code is splitting array at the middle, instead it needs to split the array about the pivot index. Take a look at [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Natecat and @rcgldr Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. My code was only sorting on the first go because recursive calls were sorting sliced copies of the array which were never returned. This goes against the definition of quicksort which is to sort in place. I updated to the following and it works.

```
def Count(num_list, first, last):
    if first < last:
        global comparisons
        comparisons += len(num_list)-1

        pivot = num_list[first]
        i = first + 1

        # quick sort
        for j in range(first+1,last):
            if num_list[j] < pivot:
                num_list[i], num_list[j] = num_list[j], num_list[i]
                i += 1

        # swap pivot with border index
        num_list[first], num_list[i-1] = num_list[i-1], num_list[first]

        # recurse
        Count(num_list, first, i-1)
        Count(num_list, i, last)
```